# List a file from all directories but skip the ones whose folder contains a specific file

Tags: ubuntu, perl, ls, gnu-parallel

I have a perl script that processes `.xml` files which reside in multiple folders under a directory. The script takes the absolute file path using the output of `ls` using parallel.

```
parallel -j 1 /home/lf-process/parse_orders.pl ::: `ls /home/lf-process/lf-orders/2020/*/*/*/*.xml`
```

- If `.done` file is found in the folder containing the `.xml`, it exits the script. The perl script looks for a `.done` file in the folder before processing the xml.
- If no `.done` file is found, it processes the folder contents and adds a `.done` file.

`ls` will list the `.xml` file regardless of the folder containing a .done file or not but the perl script checks for it anyway and exits for the XML folders which contain the `.done` file.

How can I list the absolute paths of all XMLs except for the folders that does contain the `.done` file so that I'm not invoking a script for those orders?

i.e.

```
ls /home/lf-process/lf-orders/2020/*/*/*/*.xml
```

where XML containing folders don't have a `.done` file.

Comment: Is the `.done`-file explicitly named `.done`, or is `.done` merely the filename extension?

Comment: @AdminBee it's an explicitly named empty .done file created by the perl script once it's done reading the XML files. Definitely not a filename extension.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I thought so, but just wanted to make sure ...

Comment: @AdminBee Yup! I feel like I might have to come up with a perl script equivalent of `ls` to solve this. It's not necessarily a problem until there are a 1000 folders with XML files since the server is pretty quick to instantiate scripts and exit since the .done check is the very first thing. I'm asking here because I don't want to recreate the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use grep:

```
ls /home/lf-process/lf-orders/2020/*/*/*/*.xml | grep -v \\.done
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. I am not sure though that this is going to work, because the `ls` command will list all XML files, and your `grep` will simply sort out those XML files whose name contains the pattern `.done`. As far as I understood the question, the OP looks for a command which will return _no files at all_ for an entire subdirectory if a file called `.done` is found in that subdirectory.

Comment: AdminBee is correct, this just looks for a pattern .done in the name of the XML files to exclude from the listing. I want to list all .xmls from folders which does not have a .done file.

Comment: True, my answer is completely wrong, sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
ls /home/lf-process/lf-orders/2020/*/*/*/*.xml |
  perl -nE 'chomp: -e "$_.done" || say' |
  parallel -j 1 /home/lf-process/parse_orders.pl
```